# A helper function that stops this code from infinte recursing.

Tags: python, recursion

When I run testing1 everything is fine, but when I run testing/testing3, my function is infinite recursing. I know why, but I don't know how to make a function that handles the case. I need a helper function at the beginning of frags to check whether the given string will cause an infinite recurse. Anyone have any ideas on how to solve the problem?

```
testing = ["baa","aaag","gaaaam","mmmmb"]

testing1 = ["good", "odor", "jimmy", "roboj"]

testing3 = {"aab" , "baa"]

def solution(strings):
    original = strings[:]    
    fragmentsList = frags(strings)
    RealList = fragmentsList[len(original):]
    length = len(RealList)
    removeCounter = 0
    for x in range(0,length):
        for y in range(0,length):
            if x!=y:
                if RealList[x].find(RealList[y]) != -1 and RealList[y].find(RealList[x]) == -1:# x > y
                    RealList[y] = " "
                    removeCounter = removeCounter + 1
    for x in range(0,removeCounter):
        RealList.remove(" ")
    return RealList



def frags(strings):
    length = len(strings)
    for x in range(0,length):
        for y in range(0,length):
            if x != y:
                if fraghelper(strings[x],strings[y]) != -1:
                    toAppend = fraghelper(strings[x],strings[y])
                    for f in range(0,len(toAppend)):
                        if toAppend[f] not in strings:
                            strings.append(toAppend[f])

    if len(strings) != length:
        return frags(strings)
    else:
        return strings




def fraghelper(string1, string2):
    toReturn1 = " "
    toReturn2 = " "
    for i in reversed(range(len(string1))):
        if string2.startswith(string1[-i:]):
            toReturn1 = string1[:-i] + string2

    for i in reversed(range(len(string2))):
        if string1.startswith(string2[-i:]):
            toReturn2 = string2[:-i] + string1    

    if toReturn1 == " " and toReturn2 == " ":
        return -1
    elif toReturn1 == " ":    
        return [toReturn2]
    elif toReturn2 == " ":
        return [toReturn1]
    else:
        return [toReturn1, toReturn2]




print(testing)
print(solution(testing))
```

Comment: some comments about what your code does would have been helpful

Comment: "I know why" Will you tell us, or do we have to make sense of your code all by ourselves?

Comment: `testing3 = {"aab" , "baa"]` is a mutant `dict/list`. is frags meant to be recursive and what exactly is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `fraghelper` code finds common string between two, removes it and appends to form one.

For example, it takes `'good'` and `'odor'` and returns `'goodor'`, as `'od'` is common between the two. Similarly it does for all combinations including the new formed string `'goodor'`.

Now lets say strings are `'aab'` and `'baa'`.This returns two strings

1. `'aabaa'` (`'b'` common)
2. `'baaab'` (`'aa'` common). Now this should be `'baab'`.

Now `'aab'` will again try with `'aabaa'`. Now it will return

1. `'aabaa'` (`'aab'` common)
2. `'aabaaaab'` (`'aa'` common). Now this should be `'aabaab'`.

And this will go on forever.

Place

```
print "fraghelper",strings[x],strings[y],fraghelper(strings[x],strings[y])
```

after line number 29 to see the things yourself.

In Testing 3 this is what is happening. Same for Testing.

Your current algorithm is:

1. Compare all strings of original list two at a time
2. Create new string if possible and append to original
3. Run whole thing again with appended list (Breaks in case of strings like `'aab'`, `'baa'`, etc., as they keep on creating strings)

I think you can achieve your goal by this:

1. Compare all strings of original list two at a time
2. Create new and append to new list
3. Send new list to the function (still the recursive strings like aabaa will because failure.logic for that needs to be added.)

Comment: I have edited your answer to improve the formatting; please take more care in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot.looks a lot more legible.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for the guide to formatting your answers.